# Html.EnumDropDownListFor not showing property value as selected

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

In using the new `Html.EnumDropDownListFor` extension method in MVC 5.1, I'm running into a problem where the selected value isn't updating in the drop down based on the route attribute I'm passing to my controller action.

**View**

```
@model MemberReconWebDemo.Models.EnvironmentsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Environments";
}

<h2>Environments</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(p => p.Environment)
        @Model.Environment.ToString()
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller Action**

```
[Route("environments/{environment?}")]
public ActionResult Environments(string environment)
{
    Domain.Environment env;
    Enum.TryParse(environment, true, out env);

    return View(new EnvironmentsModel{Environment = env});
}
```

If I navigate to the route without the optional attribute and I have the `Model.Environment` property set to a static value in the controller action, that selected value shows without issue.

If I pass in a valid route attribute value, assign that to the `Model.Environment` property, the drop down isn't updated to the property value upon rendering--even though I've confirmed that the property does have a value other than the default enum value.

Comment: just to check modelstate isn't playing a part, have you checked to see if the Environment has a value in the ModelState.  this can sometimes cause problems, especially in posts etc

Comment: ModelState does have a value at the time of rendering, but the drop down selected value isn't being correctly set. I used @user2086074's suggestion below, and that worked like gangbusters, so we can safely rule out ModelState.

Answer (score 6):

I too encountered this problem today. Renaming the routes parameter to a name different from the models property worked for me.

**Controller Action**

```
[Route("environments/{envparm?}")]
public ActionResult Environments(string envparam)
{
    Domain.Environment env;
    Enum.TryParse(envparam, true, out env);

    return View(new EnvironmentsModel{Environment = env});
}
```

Comment: I have been experiencing the same issue, and as @falseidols suggests, I found the problem went away if my variable name differed.  I had an enum called UserTitle and a ViewModel property called Title.  This did not bind.  However, if I renamed property to anything else without User or Title in the name, then it all binds as expected.

Comment: This was the issue in my case as well. My action parameter was named `region` and my model property was `Region`. I changed the action parameter to `regionParam` and it's now working as expected. Thank you @falseidols.

Answer (score 1):

You Should have to try this:
use Html.DropdownlistFor

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Environment, Enum.GetValues(typeof(YourEnumType)).Cast<YourEnumType>().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.ToString(), Value = ((int)x).ToString() }))
```

Comment: What you suggested works, however I'm trying to figure out why this EnumDropDownListFor feature isn't working as expected, rather than how to pull off a dropdown list of enum values.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar error. In my case I need to pass enum value through action link as below (not working):

```
enum GroupByDate {
    Day, Month
}
class IndexViewModel {
    GroupByDate GroupByDate;
}

<a href="@Url.Action("Index", new IndexViewModel { GroupByDate = DateGroup.Month})">...</a>
```

Because controller bind enum to int you need to pass it as integer, so I changed view to next (working):

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { GroupByDate = (int) DateGroup.Month})">...</a>
```

Notice, that route values not anymore a typed ViewModel, but an anonymous type.